# add new for loop in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I'm having a problem when I try to add a new for loop.
All calculations are correct, but I can't get it right for the other varieble in`for`loop.

i have a code

```
level = 1;
for distance = 1:6
  for jj = 1:kol_real
            disp(jj)
            f_pr1 = 7;
            f_pr2 = 13 + distance;
            
            U1 = U(:, f_pr1)+U(:, f_pr2);%sum of two signals u(t) = sin(2*pi*f_0*t) with different f_0
            add_noise_norm = normrnd(0, 0.2 + (0.1 *level), [N + kol_shift, 1]);
            U_pr_norm = U1 + add_noise_norm;%add some noise
                        
            parfor dd = 1:25
                M_norm(dd, jj) = corr(U_pr_norm, U(:, dd));  % calculate correlation  
            end

            [~, zz_M_norm] = findpeaks(M_norm(:, jj), 'NPeaks', 8,'SortStr','descend'); % find peaks of correlation function
            min_M_norm(1:length(zz_M_norm),jj) =  sortrows(zz_M_norm,'ascend');% write value into two array
%            
  end

 min_M_norm_temp = min_M_norm(1:2,:);
 min_M_norm_temp(:, any(min_M_norm_temp == 0)) = [];%delete if i have one zeros element
 count_M_norm = abs(min_M_norm_temp(1, :) - min_M_norm_temp(2, :)) >= 2;% compare using some condition
 p_M_norm(distance) = sum(count_M_norm);
end
```

the result is

```
0
0
0
0
0
38
```

This seems right.

But when I try to add a new loop `for level` : :

```
for level = 1:2;
for distance = 1:6
for jj = 1:kol_real
            disp(jj)
            f_pr1 = 7;
            f_pr2 = 13 + distance;
            
            U1 = U(:, f_pr1)+U(:, f_pr2);%sum of two signals u(t) = sin(2*pi*f_0*t) with different f_0
            add_noise_norm = normrnd(0, 0.2 + (0.1 *level), [N + kol_shift, 1]);
            U_pr_norm = U1 + add_noise_norm;%add some noise
                        
            parfor dd = 1:25
                M_norm(dd, jj) = corr(U_pr_norm, U(:, dd));  % calculate correlation  
            end

            [~, zz_M_norm] = findpeaks(M_norm(:, jj), 'NPeaks', 8,'SortStr','descend'); % find peaks of correlation function
            min_M_norm(1:length(zz_M_norm),jj) =  sortrows(zz_M_norm,'ascend');% write value into two array
%            
end

 min_M_norm_temp = min_M_norm(1:2,:);
 min_M_norm_temp(:, any(min_M_norm_temp == 0)) = [];%delete if i have one zeros element
 count_M_norm = abs(min_M_norm_temp(1, :) - min_M_norm_temp(2, :)) >= 2;% compare using some condition
 p_M_norm(distance) = sum(count_M_norm);
end
 p_M_level(:,level) = p_M_norm;
end
```

the result is

```
0   38
0   38
0   38
0   38
0   35
38  38
```

I'm pretty sure the second column is wrong because when I change  `level` manually it works.
Where am I wrong?...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "when I change `level` manually it works"? How do you define "works"? What's the expected output and why?

Comment: You have undefined variables in your code, so we are unable to run it to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Because you're not pre-allocating your arrays, the size of `M_norm` changes as it grows during  the first loop iteration, but not during the second one. So `M_norm(:, jj)` gets some values from the previous iteration during the second iteration. There are other such issues in your code, I believe. You should always pre-allocate arrays (i.e. make it the right size and assign all zeros to it before the loop starts).

Comment: Thanks everyone!!
 
**@Cris Luengo**, you were right!